# React does not recognize the `tReady` prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component and when i want to use it in my code i have the follow error:
React does not recognize the `tReady` prop``My component is

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const Text = ({ t, text, ...rest }) => (
  <div {...rest}>{t(text)}</div>
);

Text.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default withTranslation()(Text);
```

I use it in another file and i get this error. I try to change my component like:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const Text= ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Text.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default withTranslation()(Text);
```

The error disapear but i have no text on my text component. How can i fix this error message ?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because of your spreading of props onto the div. When you do this: `({ t, text, ...rest })`, the `rest` object has a bunch of properties, including `tReady`. You are then passing this onto the div element, but because `tReady` isn't a valid property for a div element, it gives that message. Only pass properties on to raw HTML elements that they actually support.

The reason your second example doesn't give that error is because you're not passing `tReady` (via `rest`) onto the div

Comment: Is it a way to fix it ? because it works when i remove it (like i don't have an error) but the functionnality don't work

Comment: @Kan why are you spreading the rest of the props onto the div? Which values do you _actually_ need passed onto the div?